# Universal image loader cannot resolve getInstance

Tags: java, android, universal-image-loader

I've been trying to use the universal image loader library for android for some time now, but I can't get it to work. Whenever I try to initialise the library, I get the error "cannot resolve method getInstance()"
My code is as follows:

```
ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(this)
        ...
        .build();
ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
```

I've tried to import the library using gradle and manually, but both with no luck. 
Right now, I'm importing the library like this

```
compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.4'
```

I have tried to initialise the library in a class that extends Application, and in a class that extends Activity. I have also defined the activity and application in the manifest. 

What might cause this? 
Best regards 
Mikkel

Comment: it's not an answer, but Fresco is for me the best image library

Comment: Did you get any solution? I am using the same version of `UIL` as you are and getting the same error.

Comment: @Shubham No I didn't. I just did as HugoGresse suggested: I used the Fresco library instead.

Comment: Ok. The problem with me was that there was another Java class with same name ,i.e. `ImageLoader`. As soon as I removed it and made the necessary imports, things worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

In my case i was also using Volley in the project which also have a class named Imageloader, so instead of importing correct ImageLoader from nostra i was importing volley's ImageLoader. As soon as i corrected the import it started working fine

Answer (score 0):

Use below gradle dependency and sync it.

```
compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
```

If you still not solved than restart your android studio with invalidate caches and restart options.

Hope you solved your problem.